# Howe to do Sort in ruby

Tags: ruby

In my table i am having first_name,middle_name and last_name fields.
I want to show like First_name Middle_name Last_name in Aplhabetical order.
For some records first_name may be blank, for some records last_name may be blank, for some records middle_name may be blank. If first_name blank need to show middle_name and last_name,If middle_name blank need to first and last name, If last_name blank need to show first and middle name. At final i want to show list in Alphabetical order. How i want to approach this issue?

Comment: are you talking about plain Ruby or RubyOnRails (your table being an modelled by an ActiveRecord class)?

Comment: Yes my table being an modelled by an ActiveRecord class

Comment: Alphabetical order based on what?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution in your case.

You should detect first **`non blank`** attribute:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
 def representation
   [first_name, middle_name, last_name].detect{ |r| r.present? }.downcase
 end
end
```

**Fetch objects:**

```
@objects = YourModel.all
```

**Sort objects:**

```
@objects.sort! { |a,b| a.representation <=> b.representation }
```

---

Method **`present?`** is available starting from **`Rails 2.2.1`** version.

http://apidock.com/rails/v2.2.1/Object/present%3F

Accordingly to discussion in comments: **`present?`** is the same as **`!blank?`**.

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 19
def present?
  !blank?
end
```

**`blank?`** is alias of **`empty?`**.

```
def empty?
  all? { |k, v| v && v.empty? && !v.is_a?(String) }
end
```

Comment: That last one could be simplified to `@objects.sort_by {|a| a.representation}`.

Comment: Try `!r.blank?` instead of `r.present?` and see if that works.

Comment: If you have Rails version older, than 2.2.1, use method `blank?`.